# pyenv doesn't switch python at MacOS 12.6

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv, pyenv

There are quite a few questions about pyenv not working.

```bash
 pyenv versions
  system
* 3.10.13 (set by /my/current/dir/.python-version)
  3.11.5

cat /my/current/dir/.python-version
3.10.13

which python
/my/current/dir/venv_name/bin/python

python --version
Python 3.9.6
```

.zshrc contains

```bash
echo "setting PYENV_ROOT..."
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

pyenv dir looks ok

```bash
ls -la /Users/{user}/.pyenv/versions
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 ssa  staff  128 Sep 14 09:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 ssa  staff  128 Sep  6 17:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 ssa  staff  192 Sep 14 09:12 3.10.13
drwxr-xr-x  6 ssa  staff  192 Sep  6 17:49 3.11.5


/Users/{user}/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/bin/python --version
Python 3.10.13
```

What else can i try to fix?

UPD:
that 3.9.6 python was from my venv dir.

I did

```bash
deactivate

python --version
Python 3.10.13

which python     
/Users/{user}/.pyenv/shims/python
```

So I guess i did smth wrong when created venv. Not sure how do it correctly.